# How to get the value of a certain key of a nested JSON object (2nd level and in general)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a nested JSON Object called "data".

```
console.log(Object.values(data['Meta']['Symbol']));
```

That gives me every single letter/character of the value:

```
Array(3) [ "S", "A", "P" ]
```

What I want, is the whole String: "SAP"
Where is the mistake?

Things I have tried:

That gives me the whole array (including "SAP") but I just want the String i.e. value "SAP":

```
console.log(Object.values(data['Meta']
```

That gives me an empty array (of three elements):

```
console.log(Object.keys(data['Meta']['Symbol']));
```

Information that I was looking for on the internet, doesn't adress this issue.

Structure of the JSON object:

```
{
    "Meta": {
        "Symbol": "SAP"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the following what you want? `console.log(data["Meta"]["Symbol"])`

Comment: Why would you apply `Object.values` to a value, that is a string? _That's_ your mistake here.

Comment: Just use `console.log(data.Meta.Symbol);` This will give you the string `SAP` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, this is not JSON; JSON is a string. Next, if you want to turn an array into a string, use array.join("");

`console.log(data['Meta']['Symbol'].join(""));`

Comment: That's it! Unbelievable how stupid I am. Thank you for the clarification regarding JSON. Since your answer is correct and was the first one, it becomes the "solved" state.

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON object is

```
{
    "Meta": {
       "Symbol": "SAP"
    }
}
```

And you import it with `let data = JSON.parse("MY JSON")`
Then it's just `console.log(data.Meta.Symbol)`

Comment: There is no JSON in the OP's post, nor your answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Why

```js
const data = { Meta: { Symbol: 'SAP' } };

/**
 * 1. String is an object;
 * 2. Using the Objects.prototype.values method will return an array of all the values (e.g. All the characters in the String.);
 * 
 * MDN documentation
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
console.log(Object.values(data['Meta']['Symbol']));
```

**Output**

```js
[ 'S', 'A', 'P' ]
```

### How

```js
const data = { Meta: { Symbol: 'SAP' } };

/**
 * To retrieve the value of the string, you must access it using the dot notation or bracket notation.
 *
 * Dot notation: data.Meta.Symbol
 * Bracket notation: data['Meta']['Symbol']
 *
 * MDN documentation
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
console.log(data['Meta']['Symbol']);
```

**Output**

```js
SAP
```